# PIM alternative to Outlook that syncs through USB?

Tags: sync, usb, outlook

I find Outlook 2007 slow and bloated. Before I check Outlook 2010 to see if it's any better, I was curious to know if there's a PIM (Personal Information Manager) that can sync with Android smartphones through USB.

At this point, [EssentialPIM](http://www.essentialpim.com/?r=android) can only sync through wifi. Ditto for [MyLifeOrganized](http://www.mylifeorganized.net/), which only handles to-do lists anyway.

Is there just no USB-capable alternative to MS Outlook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are obviously running Windows, you might want to take a look at [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/) and the [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client). This allows you to sync your contacts with Outlook, GMail, Windows contacts, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey, Lotus Notes and Tobit David, your calendars with Outlook, Google, Sunbird, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey, Windows calendar(Vista), Rainlendar, Lotus Notes, Tobit David and net shared calendars (WebDAV, FTP, local), SMS and more as well, and offers many additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Companionlink](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companionlink.clusbsync) as my PIM. Don't get why it only gets 3.6 from reviews on Google Play, because it works great between my Outlook 2103 and my Android Phone (Zopo C2). I guess it may be that people won't read how to correctly set it up. If you have problems syncing it through USB because of driver problems (and yes there's so many Android flavors out there you'll get driver problems some times) just use the network feature to sync.

I haven't used other solutions since this work really great for me.

/JJ